# Photon Multiplayer, Both players create their own rooms

Tags: cocos2d-x-3.0, photon

I am using Photon with cocos2dx for making a multiplayer game. When I create room from one player, it creates room successfully and after 4 or 5 seconds when I join room from other player then both player join each other successfully and game starts. The problem comes when I start game from both sides together, both players thinks that there is no room exist they both create their own rooms and unable to join each other.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `opJoinRoom`, setting `createIfNotExists`to true.
Doing so will have the first player create the room and the second one joining in.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working perfect now. I was using opJoinRandomRoom which was causing problem which I posted before. I want to ask one more thing that how to set the properties with opJoinRoom, it does not have such option because I want to set a filter that only players with same skill can join each other (just like 8 pool ball). Like player with skill 9 can join player with skill 7 to 11. How can I achieve this.

Comment: 'opJoinRandomRoom' allows you to filter for specific properties like player skills. See http://doc.photonengine.com/en/realtime/current/reference/matchmaking-and-lobby for examples.

Comment: I was using the same thing before but because of that issue (both player create their own rooms) I changed opJoinRandomRoom to opJoinRoom, setting createIfNotExiststo true. Is it possible for me to achieve this type of match making with opJoinRoom. Thanks.

Comment: `opJoinRoom`is meant to join a known room only.
For skillbased matchmaking please use `opJoinRandomRoom`.

If you would really like to go that way you could think of a naming scheme for your rooms and look up matching room from within the lobby and then join any matches by their then known name ... not something recommended though.

Comment: Yes, I really want to go with opJoinRandomRoom because of skill base match making but with that issue is same that when I send game request from two players together, they both create their own rooms and not join each other. How to overcome that issue.

Comment: In that case you will have to create the game you are looking for explicitely when no match is found using `opCreateRoom`.

When you add x retries and give players the option to retry after x times again or create a matching room themselves to wait for others to join in that should get you covered?

You might also consider broadening the searched for skillset with each retry.